# Angular delete a record from the database

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to delete a record from the database using angular services. I created a method in my mvc controller but I don't know how to call this method and pass the id.

```
    [HttpPost]
        public static void DeleteRecord(int settingID)
        {
            try
            {
                using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connStringApps))
                {
                    conn.Open();
                    using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("DeleteCurrentRecord", conn))
                    {
                        command.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                        command.Parameters.Add("@SettingId", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = settingID;
                        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        command.Parameters.Clear();
                    }
                    conn.Close();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.Write(ex.ToString());
            }

        }


        myApp.service("deleteService", function ($rootScope) {
            this.removeRow = function (recId) {

            }
        });


         myApp.controller('myController', ['$scope','deleteService',
          function ($scope, deleteService) {

              $scope.deleteRecordFromDB = function (recId) {
                  //record id is the Id of the record that I want to delete
              }
              ;
          }
        ]);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
  myApp.service("deleteService", function ($rootScope, $http) {
        this.removeRow = function (recId) {

        $http.delete(url, {params: {recordId:recId}})
        .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
            window.location.reload();
        })
        .error(function (data, status, header, config) {
        });
      }
  });

  myApp.controller('myController', ['$scope', 'deleteService', function ($scope, deleteService) {
      $scope.deleteRecordFromDB = function (recId) {
          deleteService.removeRow(recId); 
      };
  }
  ]);
```

You can access recordId by HttpGet method on server side.

Comment: Thank you. Do I need to do anything else when I am adding the service to the controller? Could you please show me how to access it with httpGet on the server side as well.

Comment: Yes. You have to call the service method,  $scope.deleteRecordFromDB = function (recId) {
                 deleteService.removeRow(recId);
              }
              ;

Comment: Thank you. I am getting the error that $http is not defined. Could you please show me how to access it with httpGet on the server side as well

Comment: See updated code, you need to add $http service to your deleteService.

Comment: Thank you . Does my method on the server side needs to be [HttpGet]. And could you show me how to access the value 'recID' from the URL